# PDO Excute with multiple OR

Tags: php, pdo

Below is the code I am using to dynamically load news articles to a web page. $dbConn->execute fires correctly when passing a single

 `WHERE (SELECT * FROM newsitem WHERE subcategoryID=12 ORDER BY posted DESC)` 

but fails to return a result when passing

```
(SELECT * FROM newsitem WHERE subcategoryID=1 || subcategoryID=12 || subcategoryID=27 || subcategoryID=27 || subcategoryID=28 || subcategoryID=29 || subcategoryID=30 || subcategoryID=31 || subcategoryID=32 || subcategoryID=43 ORDER BY posted DESC)
```

This is the code behind which generates the above queries:

`$strHTML = "";
        $strHTML .= "";

```
    if(strpos($params['subcatid'], "|") < 0){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM newsitem WHERE subcategoryID=".$params['subcatid']." ORDER BY posted DESC";
    } else {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM newsitem WHERE ";
        $idArr = explode("|", $params['subcatid']);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($idArr); $i++){
            $q .= "subcategoryID=".$idArr[$i]." || ";
        }
        $q = substr($q, 0, -4)." ORDER BY posted DESC";
    }
    return $q;

    $pstmt = $dbConn->prepare($q);
    $pstmt->execute();

    for($i = 0; $i < $params['numarts']; $i++){
        $row = $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($i == 0){
            $startArt = $row['newsitemID'];
        }
        $strHTML .= "<a href='javascript:cNews.get(".$row['newsitemID'].")'>".$row['headline']."</a><br />";
    }
    $numPages = ceil($pstmt->rowCount() / 10);
    $strHTML .= "<div id='articleNav' style='font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px; width: 50%;'>Page: 1 of ".$numPages."<img src='/files/images/sitewide/next.gif' style='float: right;''></div>";
    $strHTML .= "<div id='startArticleID' style='visibility: hidden;'>".$startArt."</div></div><div id='newsarticle' style='padding-top: 20px;'>&nbsp;</div>";
    //return $params['id']." ".$params['subcatid'];
    return $strHTML;`
```

When running this function `$params['subcatid']` is passed either `subcatid='12'` or a pipe separated list `subcatid='1|12|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|44'`. The query is generated, then prepared, executed. As stated when there is only one `subcategoryID` the results are returned as expected; no results are returned when multiple OR `subcategoryID` is passed.

I tested this by copying and pasting the queries to the database directly and both return results as expected.

What could be happening when passing the complex query?

Comment: use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/comparison-operators.html) -- _IN (value,...)_

Comment: The return value of `strpos` is never `<0`. I think you want to check for `===false` in the very first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have been told in the comments, multiple ORs can be substituted with very handy IN operator.

Yet it is not that easy to make it with **prepared statements**. Here you go:

One have to create a query with placeholders representing every array member, and then bind this array values for execution:

```
$ids = explode("|", $params['subcatid']);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works great when there are more then 1 in the array of values. But now, when I run the same code with an array of a length of 1 it returns no results. Any suggestions on what would cause it to return no results? 

I have tested the array using is_array() true, used count() result 1. but when the prepared statement executes no results are returned. I even echoed the query as a start mysql query, ran it in phpmyadmin and return 478 results. Thanks

Comment: What is the array exact contents?

Comment: Found my answer.... The problem was not PDO or the prepare. The problem came from my tinymce editor inserting 2 span tags into the html which means under code it would not get a true value and did not show its ugly head in code as the single length array would say 12 white debugging, but in reality it was "<span...>12</span>"... Once this erroneous information was removed it pulls correctly with a single length array.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this with a SQL `OR`, but instead do it with `IN`

Example assuming id is an integer:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM newsitem WHERE ";

$idArr = explode("|", $params['subcatid']);
$placeholders = array_fill(0,count($idArr),'?');
$placeholders_str = implode(',',$placeholders);

$q .= "subCategoryId IN ($placeholders_str)";    

$q .= " ORDER BY posted DESC";
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm not doing any validation here, just demonstrating the logic.

Comment: This is what you have got -1 for

Comment: Come again? You are downvoting my answer because I'm not writing the entire routine for the OP? He didn't ask how to do that. I answered the question asked.

Comment: Oh, no! Because you wrote completely wrong one. Please learn prepared statements. And nobody would have not a single objection.

Comment: Still not sure I follow. OP asked specifically about generating the query when there are multiple subCategoryId to look for. How does what I wrote not answer that question?

Comment: Because one have to use **prepared statements** instead of concatenating variables right into query. Sorry, but it was discussed zillion times already.

Comment: There updated to use placeholders for the prepared query. Like I said, my purpose was to demonstrate using the `IN` statement instead of building multiple `OR` statement